# Criar popup com Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Alguém conhece algum tutorial para criar popup no xamarin.forms usando esse plugin, Rg.Plugins.Popup? Preciso criar um popup e dentro dele um textbox ou textarea com dois botões(Ok e Cancel).

Answer (score 3):

No SOen tem uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441913/custom-popup-in-xamarin-forms/36445812#36445812) que pode te ajudar.
Neste [link](https://www.questarter.com/q/popup-dialog-with-text-input-in-xamarin-forms-27_30994191.html) também possui um outro exemplo.

---

Resumidamente você fará:

- A instalação do plugin em todos os projetos;
- Adicionar o Popup no xaml;
- Usar os métodos que eles fornecem na documentação para Mostrar/Ocultar o PopUp:

  - [`Task PushAsync`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) (PopupPage page, bool animate = true)
  - [`Task PopAllAsync`](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/master/src/Rg.Plugins.Popup/Services/PopupNavigation.cs) (bool animate = true)

Você irá usar o `PopupPage` xaml dentro de um popup de forma elegante, pois adiciona os seguintes métodos:

```
Navigation.PushPopupAsync()
Navigation.PopPopupAsync()
Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync()
Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync()
```

O exemplo abaixo ([fonte](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66406/customized-popup-page-in-xamarin-forms)) será algo parecido com o que irá criar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<t:SlidePopupView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:t="clr-namespace:SlideOverKit" 
                  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:eFACiLiTYMobile;assembly=eFACiLiTYMobile" x:Class="eFACiLiTYMobile.View.PopupScreens.CallEditEvent">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Padding="0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*" /> </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ScrollView BackgroundColor="White" Padding="15,10,15,30" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label HeightRequest="90" Text="Build some Awesome SlideOver's" FontSize="24" XAlign="Center" />
          <Button HeightRequest="60" x:Name="DoneButton" Text="Close" />
          <Entry BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="60" x:Name="txt_entry" Text="Test Application" />
          <Picker x:Name="ac_Siste" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green" />
          <DatePicker x:Name="DPRequestResolutionDate" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" >
            <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format> 
            <DatePicker.MinimumDate><sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse"><x:Arguments> <x:String>Jan 1 2000</x:String></x:Arguments></sys:DateTime></DatePicker.MinimumDate>
            <DatePicker.MaximumDate><sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse"><x:Arguments><x:String>Dec 31 2050</x:String></x:Arguments></sys:DateTime></DatePicker.MaximumDate>
          </DatePicker>          
          <Button HeightRequest="60" x:Name="ExitButton" Text="Exit"  />     
        </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
  </ContentPage.Content> 
</t:SlidePopupView>
```

Verifique a documentação oficial:
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/tree/master/src/Demo

Comment: Em realidade já havia entrado no rotorgames, mas não estava entendo algumas coisas.